About factorization theorem: if $f_P(X)=g_P(T(X))h(X)$ and $h$ is not integrable, can we conclude that $T(X)$ is sufficient?
According to this note, we have the following theorem:

Factorization Theorem: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of probability measures on a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{B})$,
dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$. Then a statistic $T(X)$
is sufficient for $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if there exists a
measurable function $h\geq 0$ on $S$ such that for each
$P\in\mathcal{P}$ there is a measurable function $g_P$ such that
$f_P(X)=g_P(T(X))h(X)$.

My question is: is that proposition true even if $h$ is not integrable? I was able to obtain a proof of that theorem assuming that $h$ is integrable. If it's actually true in the case in which $h$ isn't integrable, how can I prove it?
Thank you for your attention!
